# public static void main() not working?

Tags: java

Here's the code.

```
    import java.io.*;
class Time
{
 int a,b,c,Total;
 Time()
 {
  int hr=0;
  int sec=0;
  int min=0;
 }
 void time(int hr, int min, int sec)
 {
  a=hr;
  b=min;
  c=sec;
 }
 void compute()
 {
  Total=a*3600+b*60+c*1;

 }
 void display()
 {
  System.out.println("Number of hours = " +a);
  System.out.println("Number of minutes = " +b);
  System.out.println("Number of seconds = " +c);
  System.out.println("Total number of seconds = " +Total);
 }
 public static void main()throws IOException
 {
  BufferedReader pd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
  System.out.println("Enter number of hours : ");
  int x=Integer.parseInt(pd.readLine());
  System.out.println("Enter number of minutes : ");
  int y=Integer.parseInt(pd.readLine());
  System.out.println("Enter number of seconds : ");
  int z=Integer.parseInt(pd.readLine());
  Time obj=new Time();
  obj.time(x,y,z);
  obj.compute();
  obj.display();
  System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
 }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why public static void main() is not working? I'm new to coding, so this might be a dumb question.

Comment: `main(String[] args)`

Comment: When you say "not working", what happens when you try to compile or run it?

Answer (score 1):

Method signature is wrong. It should be public `static void main(String [] args)throws IOException` **instead of** `static void main()throws IOException`

Answer (score 0):

Method signature is wrong.You should change

```
public static void main()throws IOException
```

to

```
public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
```

Answer (score 0):

main () takes an array argument of type String.

This is required and one can read data from command line by executing java program as:

```
java <public class name/java file name> arg1 arg2 ...
```

One can get these arguments inside main as

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
                    for (int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(args[i]);
                    }
.
.
.
.

                    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what that would do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Are you asking what String args[] in main does  or about java code execution from command line ?